# Trying to Create a Crystal Report that shows members in/out during a shift

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crosstab, date-range, subreport

I am on a 64 bit windows 7 pro machine using Crystal Report 13 sp 5.  I am pulling from an Oracle database.

**I am trying to create a spread sheet like report that shows by day the number of members who signed in and the number of members who signed out for a date range during a shift span.**

Example, 4 columns:   DATE DAY  IN  OUT (Jan 1, 2015 Monday  25  15).

So I thought I would create a sub-report for each of the two shifts Day 06:00 to 17:59 and Night 18:00 05:59 and use a cross tab object to sum the number of members who signed in and a second cross tab object for the number of members who singed out during that day and that shift.

So, at this point I have the Day Shift sub -report lay out with a title at the top saying DAY SHIFT 06:00 - 17:59 then two cross tab objects in the footer, one for signed in and one for signed out each with two columns one formatted to show the date as Jan xx, Fri and the second column shows the sum of members who signed in/out.  I don't have the selection criteria yet.

This whole report is date range driven.  Example:  Manager runs report for month of July to see each day broken out by signed in signed out for day shift and right next to it on the same page with no more than one month per page the same two cross tab object but in a sub report for night shift.

This report only uses one table so it should be easy!  But I can't figure out how to have a client enter the date range that drives two sub reports to pull and sum the memTable.signedIN data and the memTable.signedOUT for that date range with the return data displayed per day and date, during a specific time frame.

I am certainly in a pickle, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using parameters

Comment: yep, i did a startdate and an enddate on my main report and I figured I could hard code the shift times on the sub report since they don't change I just can't figure out how to put it all together and pass the user selected date range to the each sub report

Comment: Hi Siva, are you available?

Comment: Hi meg...yeah i am available..tell me any issue

Comment: sorry had a meeting, I'm still working on this silly shift roster but i wanted to say creating the dynamic params worked perfectly.  thank you for the assist!  I'm almost done but hit a snag trying to filter my running total on a formula that takes the date and time a member is signed in and totals it into two day shift or night shift.

Comment: Ok but what is the issue here? Any error

Comment: this is the formula:  for running total are summary by membertable.id, summary type = count, evaluate = use formula: {membertable.signedIN} in CDATETIME(DatePart("yyyy", {membertable.signedIN}), DatePart("m", {membertable.signedIN}), DatePart("d", {membertable.signedIN}), 6, 0, 0) to
CDATETIME(DatePart("yyyy", {membertable.signedIN}), DatePart("m", {membertable.signedIN}), DatePart("d", {membertable.signedIN}), 17, 59, 0), and finally reset = on change of group membertable.signedINdate which is a date/time type -- in prev msg i said formula totals into day or  night but meant filters

Comment: your formula for running doesn't looks like it works as it looks like a record selection formula

Comment: Your so right Siva, I had to scrap the formula and create a new Time Test formula that forces just the time out of the time/date field.  Then I did a new much simpler formula {@time_test} >= time(6, 00, 00)
and {@time_test} <= time(17, 59, 00).  The report is working fine but the client has come back requesting the report be broken out further by month and paged break on the month.  I don't know how to do that since the main report displays the results of 4 sub-reports...crazy!  Thank you for your help Siva.

Comment: @Meg....no problem brother... are you able to achieve your new requirememt or do you need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dynamic parameters so that date is picked from databse.

Now in sub report also create same paraneters... and link those parameters using sub report links which will ensure data is passed to sub reports